# How did Stack Overflow get its Twitter account?

Tags: discussion, twitter

What was involved in Stack Exchange acquiring the [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackoverflow) account [@StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/@stackoverflow)?

It used to have [another owner](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330143635/https://twitter.com/StackOverflow) for a long time.

Was it purchased? 
Acquired via Twitter management? 
Taken over by SE  Operation Specialists, hopefully with minimal casualties?

Comment: Guile. And wit. Guile and wit.

Comment: looks like they [hacked it](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3737539#3737539)

Comment: Currently 1343 followers. Just saying to compare if there is some meta effect after this.

Comment: @sergioFC They had a [perfectly appropriate number of followers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wv9Cn.png) prior to the first tweet...

Comment: "Jon Skeet does not follow stackoverflow; stackoverflow follows him."

Comment: ... so that's where my smiting stick went ...

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Cool, something more to add to [Jon Skeet facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts). The hacking theory seems to be the correct one, [their tweets](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/623929452158914561) are awesome.

Comment: Looks hacked, but probably not by StackOverflow...

Comment: @Scimonster - Well that's disappointing. I thought the account owner was kidding with that tweet and SE actually got the account.

Comment: @BSMP The account [is operated by SE currently](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/623924360273903617).

Comment: Most probably a request to both Twitter's legal dept. and the previous owner.

Comment: The previous owner would have made some big bucks :/

Comment: IIRC Twitter accounts can be acquired, if you have a legal trademark in the respective country of the owner. Note: I don't support this, since it sucks for the previous owner.

Comment: @Leandros Are you the previous owner?

Comment: Can the term "StackOverflow" be trademarked? It's been in existence far longer that this site. Twitter founded 2006. SO founded 2008, what if the owner had the account since before then?

Comment: So what if used by some other person ? Its not a domain name ..Stack-overflow can use some other name and people easily know the Stackoverflow official account you can see plenty of big companies government agencies used some other name in Twitter rather than their actual name because its already used occupied by someone..It could be a legal issue but hard to achieve.Rather you can create another account and get Blue Mark(Authorize account ) from Twitter, its not a big deal so rather going to legal battle use some better option .

Comment: @jammykam Twitter shows the account as created in April 2010.

Comment: The previous owner's [about.me page](https://about.me/bernardpoon) is still linked to @StackOverflow... maybe he doesn't know?

Comment: They've been waiting some time, with previous mentions of inactivity by the previous owner on meta. I'd bet he went 6 months without activity. https://support.twitter.com/articles/15362-inactive-account-policy

Comment: @jammykam IANAL, but yes, I believe it can be trademarked for the use of a brand name. The term "stack overflow" has been around for a long time in reference to code, obviously, but its name as a brand is what the trademark protects. Stack Overflow wouldn't be able to enforce the trademark against actual coding languages or anything that calls something a stack overflow in a technical sense, only to protect its brand.

Comment: @NormalHuman April 2010 is for the current ownership (which is strange...). But WayBackMachine shows post from the original owner dated 14 March 2008: https://web.archive.org/web/20081025012435/http://twitter.com/stackoverflow and Stackover

Comment: @Vaindil IANAL either, but Stackoverflow purportedly [launched in August 2008](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow+launch+date) but WBM shows posts from 14/Mar/08. Bit tight on timelines, not sure they could claim brand ownership over it in this case. I imagine the most likely answer is the one given by JackArbiter

Comment: @jammykam Oh, sorry, I didn't mean SO claiming trademark to get the Twitter account, I was just speaking in general.

Comment: [14,444 followers](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/followers) now. #justForTheRecord :D

Comment: 25.9K followers as of today [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackoverflow?lang=en)

Comment: Seems to me like they hacked it... Bernard Poon, the original owner, tweeted on that account "I think someone is trying to hack me". May be unrelated, but a little fishy.